# text alignment inside a treecolumn

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a treecolumn defined like so:

```
{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
    flex: 1,
    dataIndex: 'text',
    cellWrap: true
}
```

And it looks like so:

[image]

But I want to align text a little different:

[image]

The desired picture is made in Paint, while I want to achieve the same effect in ExtJS. PS. I'm using ExtJS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using **cellTpl** property. You will need to fix the css in template to get text align properly.

You can find default cellTpl value for latest 6.5.x version at : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/src/Column.js-2.html

Sencha fiddle is giving many dependency errors for extjs 6.x dependencies so created a poc with extjs 5.0.

Here working POC code for same (extjs 5.x):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH report',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH lottery tickets',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }
        });

        var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            title: 'Simple Tree',
            width: 300,
            id: "treee",
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                flex: 1,
                title: "COLNAME",
                dataIndex: 'text',
                cellWrap: true,
                cellTpl: [
                    '<tpl for="lines">',
                        '<img src="{parent.blankUrl}" class="{parent.childCls} {parent.elbowCls}-img ',
                        '{parent.elbowCls}-<tpl if=".">line<tpl else>empty</tpl>" role="presentation"/>',
                    '</tpl>',
                    '<div style="display:inline-flex">',
                        '<img src="{blankUrl}" style="width:28px" class="{childCls} {elbowCls}-img {elbowCls}',
                            '<tpl if="isLast">-end</tpl><tpl if="expandable">-plus {expanderCls}</tpl>" role="presentation"/>',
                        '<tpl if="checked !== null">',
                            '<input type="button" {ariaCellCheckboxAttr}',
                                ' class="{childCls} {checkboxCls}<tpl if="checked"> {checkboxCls}-checked</tpl>"/>',
                        '</tpl>',

                            '<img src="{blankUrl}" style="width:28px" role="presentation" class="{childCls} {baseIconCls} ',
                                '{baseIconCls}-<tpl if="leaf">leaf<tpl else>parent</tpl> {iconCls}"',
                                '<tpl if="icon">style="background-image:url({icon})"</tpl>/>',
                            '<tpl if="href">',
                                '<a href="{href}" role="link" target="{hrefTarget}" class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</a>',
                            '<tpl else>',
                                '<span class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</span>',
                    '</div>',
                    '</tpl>'
                ],
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            laypout: 'fit',
            items: [tree],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Working fiddle (extjs 5.0): https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2clm

### Edit

Sencha fiddle fixed the issue with dependencies.

Working solution with extjs 6.5.3:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            fields: ['text'],
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH report',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'SOME LONG TEXT RIGHT HERE BLAH BLAH BLAH lottery tickets',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }
        });

        var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            store: treeStore,
            width: 300,
            rootVisible: false,
            selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                title: "COLNAME",
                dataIndex: 'text',
                flex: 1,
                cellWrap: true,
                cellTpl: [
                    '<tpl for="lines">',
                        '<div class="{parent.childCls} {parent.elbowCls}-img ',
                        '{parent.elbowCls}-<tpl if=".">line<tpl else>empty</tpl>" role="presentation"></div>',
                    '</tpl>',
                    '<div style="display:inline-flex">',
                        '<div class="{childCls} {elbowCls}-img {elbowCls}',
                            '<tpl if="isLast">-end</tpl><tpl if="expandable">-plus {expanderCls}</tpl>" role="presentation"></div>',
                        '<tpl if="checked !== null">',
                            '<div role="button" {ariaCellCheckboxAttr}',
                                ' class="{childCls} {checkboxCls}<tpl if="checked"> {checkboxCls}-checked</tpl>"></div>',
                        '</tpl>',
                        '<tpl if="glyph">',
                            '<span class="{baseIconCls}" ',
                            '<tpl if="glyphFontFamily">',
                                'style="font-family:{glyphFontFamily}"',
                            '</tpl>',
                            '>{glyph}</span>',
                        '<tpl else>',
                            '<tpl if="icon">',
                                '<img src="{blankUrl}"',
                            '<tpl else>',
                                '<div',
                            '</tpl>',
                            ' role="presentation" class="{childCls} {baseIconCls} {customIconCls} ',
                            '{baseIconCls}-<tpl if="leaf">leaf<tpl else><tpl if="expanded">parent-expanded<tpl else>parent</tpl></tpl> {iconCls}" ',
                            '<tpl if="icon">style="background-image:url({icon})"/><tpl else>></div></tpl>',
                        '</tpl>',
                        '<tpl if="href">',
                            '<a href="{href}" role="link" target="{hrefTarget}" class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</a>',
                        '<tpl else>',
                            '<span class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</span>',
                        '</tpl>',
                    '</div>'
                ],
            }]
        });

        var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: "Sample panel",
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [treePanel]
        });
    }
});
```

cellTpl config for ExtJS 6.5.3:

```
        cellTpl: [
            '<tpl for="lines">',
                '<div class="{parent.childCls} {parent.elbowCls}-img ',
                '{parent.elbowCls}-<tpl if=".">line<tpl else>empty</tpl>" role="presentation"></div>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<div style="display:inline-flex">',
                '<div class="{childCls} {elbowCls}-img {elbowCls}',
                    '<tpl if="isLast">-end</tpl><tpl if="expandable">-plus {expanderCls}</tpl>" role="presentation"></div>',
                '<tpl if="checked !== null">',
                    '<div role="button" {ariaCellCheckboxAttr}',
                        ' class="{childCls} {checkboxCls}<tpl if="checked"> {checkboxCls}-checked</tpl>"></div>',
                '</tpl>',
                '<tpl if="glyph">',
                    '<span class="{baseIconCls}" ',
                    '<tpl if="glyphFontFamily">',
                        'style="font-family:{glyphFontFamily}"',
                    '</tpl>',
                    '>{glyph}</span>',
                '<tpl else>',
                    '<tpl if="icon">',
                        '<img src="{blankUrl}"',
                    '<tpl else>',
                        '<div',
                    '</tpl>',
                    ' role="presentation" class="{childCls} {baseIconCls} {customIconCls} ',
                    '{baseIconCls}-<tpl if="leaf">leaf<tpl else><tpl if="expanded">parent-expanded<tpl else>parent</tpl></tpl> {iconCls}" ',
                    '<tpl if="icon">style="background-image:url({icon})"/><tpl else>></div></tpl>',
                '</tpl>',
                '<tpl if="href">',
                    '<a href="{href}" role="link" target="{hrefTarget}" class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</a>',
                '<tpl else>',
                    '<span class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</span>',
                '</tpl>',
            '</div>'
        ],
```

Working fiddle with Extjs 6.5.3: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2clq

Comment: Thanks! It looks promissing. But can you please share, how new tpl should look like for ExtJS 6? A code snippet without any fiddle will be enough.

Comment: @Jacobian Updated the answer with cellTpl config and a working fiddle with 6.5.3

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to put it in other direction like this

```
{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
     flex: 1,
     dataIndex: 'text',
     cellWrap: true
}
```

Comment: What were you trying to say? Please edit your answer to a more clear format

Comment: I see no difference with my current configuration